# HTTP and Angular: Observable Vs Angular Promise

Tags: angular

I want to propagate the result of an HTTP response.

In this case I want my AuthGuard to call a service, then return one property of the response.

Service:

```
export class AuthService {
    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }

    check(): Observable<AuthStatus> {
         return this
          .http
          .get<AuthStatus>('./assets/mock-services/auth/check.json')

    }
}
```

Guard:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(protected auth: AuthService) { }

    canActivate(): boolean {
        let status: AuthStatus;

        this.auth.check(); // <-- what to do here?
    }
}
```

`AuthStatus` is a simple interface with one only attribute: `authenticated`.
What i want to do in the canActivate method is to unwrap the response and return the boolean `status.authenticated` field but I'm not sure how I should do that.

What i would have done with angularjs:

```
$scope.check= function() {
    return $http.get('foo'); // returns json { result: true }
}

$scope.canActivate= function() {
    return $scope.check().then(function(response){
        return response.data.result;
    });
}
```

Now this Angular code doesn't make any sense obviously, it's only there to explain how I used to do things.

How should I deal with async observables in order to operate on the data once it's available?

Comment: `canActivate` also supports `Observable<boolean>` as a return type...

Answer (score 1):

You can return an observable from an auth guard. Like that

```
    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.auth.check().pipe(
            map(({ authenticated }) => authenticated)
        );
    }
```

Comment: Or just [`pluck("authenticated")`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pluck).